# I want to get unixtime in Datepicker

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am using react, typescript.
Datepicker uses react-dates.
I want to select unix time when I select a date.
If anyone is familiar with react-dates, please let me know.

[enter link description here](https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-cray-pxsny?file=/src/App.tsx:0-1107)

```
import { DayPickerRangeController } from "react-dates";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import moment from "moment";

import "moment/locale/ja"; 
import "react-dates/initialize";
import "react-dates/lib/css/_datepicker.css";

export default function App() {
  const dateFormat = "YYYY/MM/DD";
  const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState<moment.Moment | null>(null);
  const [endDate, setEndDate] = useState<moment.Moment | null>(null);
  const [focusedInput, setFocusedInput] = useState<"startDate" | "endDate">(
    "startDate"
  );

  console.log(startDate);
  return (
    <DayPickerRangeController
      startDate={startDate}
      endDate={endDate}
      focusedInput={focusedInput}
      numberOfMonths={2}
      onFocusChange={(focusedInput) => {
        setFocusedInput(!focusedInput ? "startDate" : focusedInput);
      }}
      onDatesChange={(selectedDates) => {
        if (focusedInput === "startDate") {
          setStartDate(selectedDates.startDate);
        } else {
          setEndDate(selectedDates.endDate);
        }
      }}
    />
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  console.log(new Date(startDate).getTime() / 1000);
```

Comment: ```No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 4, '(value: string | number | Date): Date', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'Moment | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | number | Date'.
      Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string | number | Date'.
  Overload 2 of
```

Comment: If you do console.log(new Date(startDate).getTime() / 1000); you will get a ts error. Do you know how to solve this?

Comment: Well, just check that `startDate` is not null, upfront. Like this 
`console.log(startDate && new Date(startDate).getTime() / 1000);`